# Automating tests using Xray, Robot Framework, and GitLab: How to get started?

Tags: testing, gitlab, robotframework, cicd, jira-xray

I'm looking to automate tests for my project using Xray, Robot Framework With python , and GitLab, but I'm unsure of how to proceed. Could someone provide guidance on how to set up the automation workflow?

Know how to automate test using this tools

Answer (score 0):

The overall flow would be something like this, assuming you're adopting ATDD:
[image: Robot Framework integration with Xray]

If you're using Xray on Jira Datacenter, you can see here a [detailed tutorial](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Robot+Framework+integration+in+Python+or+Java) showcasing some automated tests implemented in Robot Framework and then the integration with Xray; there's a [GibHub repo with the sample code](https://github.com/bitcoder/WebDemo) used.

So, and focusing on the essential, you would:

- write  your Robot Framework tests
- execute your tests as usual in RF, (e.g.,  `robot ...`), which will produce and output.xml report
- submit that report to Xray using Xray's REST API; there are specific endpoints to handle RF output.xml type of reports; if you're using Xray on Jira Datacenter please see [this](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-RobotFrameworkXMLresults); if you're using Xray on Jira Cloud please see [this](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST+v2#ImportExecutionResultsRESTv2-RobotFrameworkXMLresults) instead.

As an example, to submit the RF report to Xray on Jira Datacenter, you can make a POST request using something like this (assuming you have `curl` tool):

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u someuser:somepass -F "file=@output.xml" "http://192.168.56.102/rest/raven/2.0/import/execution/robot?projectKey=CALC
```

If you're using Xray on Jira Cloud, there's a somehow [similar tutorial](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Testing+using+Robot+Framework+integration+in+Python+or+Java).

To setup this on Gitlab, you should create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in your repository.

```yaml
# Official language image. Look for the different tagged releases at:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/tags/
image: python:3.12.2

# Change pip's cache directory to be inside the project directory since we can
# only cache local items.
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/
cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip

stages:
  - execute_automated_tests
  - upload_test_results

before_script:
  - python --version ; pip --version  # For debugging
  - pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - apt-get update



test:
  stage: execute_automated_tests
  before_script: | 
    set -e
    apt-get install -yqq unzip curl
    # Install Chrome & chromedriver
    curl -sS -o - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
    echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    apt update && apt install google-chrome-stable -y
  http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
    wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/121.0.6167.85/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
    ls -la /tmp/chromedriver.zip
    unzip -j /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/
    nohup python demoapp/server.py &
  script: |
    google-chrome --version && \
    chromedriver -v && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    robot -x junit.xml -o output.xml login_tests || true
  allow_failure: true
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - output.xml
    when: always

  
upload_results_to_xray:
  stage: upload_test_results
  script:
    - echo "uploading results to Xray..."
    - 'curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u $XRAY_USERNAME:$XRAY_PASSWORD -F "file=@output.xml" "$XRAY_SERVER_URL/rest/raven/2.0/import/execution/robot?projectKey=$PROJECT_KEY"'
    - echo "done"
  dependencies:
  - test
```

Don't forget to add the environment variables on your GitLab CI/CD configuration, under the Pipeline area in Gitlab's UI.

When you run this, either manually or because of a commit, the workflow will be run on Gitlab, and there you can see the information on the Test Execution issue created on Xray; in the screenshot it shows "CALC-408".

[image: Gitlab job output]

If you go to your Jira/Xray instance, you'll be able to see the new Test Execution along with the results.

[image: Test Execution issue in Xray with Robot Framework results]

Note: Xray may support RF up to version 6.x; not the latest RF 7.0.

============ ============ ============ ============

If you were using CircleCI as CI/CD tool, the process would be quite similar; I'll share it as I started by implementing it using CircleCI initially to prepare the answer for you.

To setup this on CircleCI, you should create a  `.circleci/config.yml` file in your repository, and add something like the following (dont forget to create some environment variables in your CircleCI project configuration):

```yaml
# Use the latest 2.1 version of CircleCI pipeline process engine.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference

# For a detailed guide to building and testing with Python, read the docs:
# https://circleci.com/docs/language-python/ for more details
version: 2.1

# Orbs are reusable packages of CircleCI configuration that you may share across projects, enabling you to create encapsulated, parameterized commands, jobs, and executors that can be used across multiple projects.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/orb-intro/
orbs:
  # See the Python orb documentation here: https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/python
  python: circleci/python@2.1.1
  browser-tools: circleci/browser-tools@1.4.6
  
# Define a job to be invoked later in a workflow.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/jobs-steps/#jobs-overview & https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#jobs
jobs:
  build-and-test:
    # Specify the execution environment. You can specify an image from Docker Hub or use one of our convenience images from CircleCI's Developer Hub.
    # See: https://circleci.com/docs/executor-intro/ & https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#executor-job
    docker:
      # Specify the version you desire here
      # See:https://circleci.com/developer/images/image/cimg/python
      - image: cimg/python:3.12-browsers

    # Add steps to the job
    # See: https://circleci.com/docs/jobs-steps/#steps-overview & https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#steps
    steps:
      # Checkout the code as the first step.
      - checkout
      - python/install-packages:
          pkg-manager: pip
          # app-dir: ~/project/package-directory/  # If your requirements.txt isn't in the root directory.
          # pip-dependency-file: test-requirements.txt  # if you have a different name for your requirements file, maybe one that combines your runtime and test requirements.
      # get server up and running in the background
      - run:
          name: Run webserver to be target by tests
          command: python demoapp/server.py
          background: true
      - run:
          name: Run tests
          # This assumes Robot Framework is installed via the install-package step above
          command: robot -x junit.xml -o output.xml login_tests || true
      - run:
          name: Upload results to Xray DC
          command: |
            echo uploading RF output.xml, if available, to Xray...
            [ -f output.xml ] && curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u $XRAY_USERNAME:$XRAY_PASSWORD -F "file=@output.xml" "$XRAY_SERVER_URL/rest/raven/2.0/import/execution/robot?projectKey=$PROJECT_KEY"
      - store_test_results:
          path: junit.xml
          when: always

# Orchestrate jobs using workflows
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/workflows/ & https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#workflows
workflows:
  sample: # This is the name of the workflow, feel free to change it to better match your workflow.
    # Inside the workflow, you define the jobs you want to run.
    jobs:
      - build-and-test
```

When you run this, either manually or because of a commit, the workflow will be run on CircleCI, and there you can see the information on the Test Execution issue created on Xray; in the screenshot it shows "CALC-395", even though CircleCI redacted the project key (i.e. "CALC").

[image: CircleCI job output]

If you go to your Jira/Xray instance, you'll be able to see the new Test Execution along with the results.

[image: Test Execution showing the Robot Framework test results]